# Error: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ng-form"

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am using angular 2 typescript.I am having trouble while using ngForm in my template.Other files are working fine but when i open register file in localhost there is an error in the console as **Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ng-form" (""col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
    ]#f="ng-form">**  my register.component.html file

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
<form (ngSubmit)="onSignup(f)" #f="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input
    ngModel
     type="email"
     id="email"
     name="email"

     class="form-control"
     required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input
    ngModel
      type="password"
      id="password"
      name="password"
      ngModel
      class="form-control"
      required>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid">Sign Up</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>`
```

my register.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { FormsModule, NgForm, NgModel, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({

templateUrl: 'register.component.html',

})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {


constructor() { }


ngOnInit(){}

onSignup(form: NgForm) {
 const email = form.value.email;
 const password = form.value.password;

 }


 }
```

app.component.ts file

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
// tslint:disable-next-


selector: 'body',
template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
title = 'app';

constructor(){

}

ngOnInit(){}


}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ApplicationRef, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, NgModel, NgForm, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DropdownModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { TabsModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/tabs';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES } from './shared/nav-dropdown.directive';
import { SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES } from './shared/sidebar.directive';
import { AsideToggleDirective } from './shared/aside.directive';
import { BreadcrumbsComponent } from './shared/breadcrumb.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { FullLayoutComponent } from './layouts/full-layout.component';
import { SimpleLayoutComponent } from './layouts/simple-layout.component';

@NgModule({

declarations: [

AppComponent,

FullLayoutComponent,
SimpleLayoutComponent,
NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES,
BreadcrumbsComponent,
SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES,
AsideToggleDirective,



 ],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
DropdownModule.forRoot(),
TabsModule.forRoot(),
ChartsModule,
CommonModule,
FormsModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],

providers: [{
provide: LocationStrategy,
useClass: HashLocationStrategy
 }],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ] 
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any Help will be appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: The rror you quoted mentions ng-form, but your code shows ngForm. Which one is it?

Comment: same error on both ng-form or ngForm i have updated on code and post it here but the error if from old file. Sorry for this.

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? And is the register component shown above in the AppModule, or in a submodule?

Answer (score 1):

Try to import in the module:

```
import { NgForm, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

and add in @NgModule...

```
imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
]
```